# How to recreate a premade png pixel by pixel as a variable increases

Tags: javascript, image-processing, pixel

I'm making an idle game in unity2D with javascript and am trying to make a goal for the player by very slowly building an image based on one of several I have stored in the game's files (assume png). This image needs to reveal another pixel every time the player's total score ticks up and remove a pixel as he spends those points. With a large image this would take a fair amount of time but show progress.

I've played around with individual pixels before when I was learning python but I've never seen pixel manipulation used in this way. Any ideas would be a great help thanks.

Comment: Do you want to reveal the pixels randomly?

Comment: I'd prefer to do it in sequential order but if random was easier then I'd do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a prefab pixel sprite and sequentially layer it over the image. Store the prefabs in an array. They will already be in order, so handling hiding and showing them would be easy enough. You can hide/show via sorting layers (move them to your background layer to hide, move them back to foreground layer to show).

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers

Comment: That's a good idea except it would take a prohibitively long time to implement. I'm looking at images with around 9210600 individual images, even if the blocks used were larger than single pixels it would still take a long time.

Comment: Really? I was more worried about having millions of sprites in view. Implementation time seems pretty low to me. I see you mention going pixel by pixel, line by line in the comment above. I'm not sure you understand this could be done fairly easily with a couple loops and a few handling functions. Unity makes it more difficult since "pixels" really aren't a thing, but get the units and camera right and you should be set.

Comment: Really? Because I couldn't think of a loop that would be able to check the current score total and either add or subtract pixels depending on the current number of pixels revealed. Also meant to say "9210600 individual pixels" in my earlier comment but it didn't let me edit.

Comment: That part wouldn't be done in a loop, that would be part of the handler(s). Some simple division should handle it. The loop(s) would setup the pixel mask and accompanying array. Without knowing the details of your scoring system, I set this up for you to take a look at. It's just a logic example, but maybe it will help. http://jsfiddle.net/q7erm42v/

Comment: You're welcome :) I know you had a scoring system involved, but I didn't know details about it so I thought at least a logic/setup example might help. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

you could either adjust the size of the picture, i.e. shrinking and stretching it - if this is a simple progress bar. Or you could overlay it with e.g. a black texture and adjust its size to cover the parts of the progress bar that you don't want to show. If you want to reveal pixel on a 2d basis (e.g. line by line) you could work with two rectangular shapes to cover those parts that you don't want to show yet.
If you really want to reveal random pixels, than you can still work with masks, but bear in mind that unity2d is not meant to work like that on a per pixel basis. You might need a custom shader and that's not trivial.

Comment: Sounds like it might be more trouble than it's worth to make the image be revealed or made pixel by pixel. Doing it line by line isn't an option, same goes for shrinking and stretching.

Comment: really why is it so much trouble to have one sprite masking all the lines not yet to be shown and another sprite mask the pixel in the currently revealing line? as you can see in other comments: thinking pixel by pixel is not the way to go in unity. Performance-wise it's probaly much faster to fake this pixel by pixel revealing. The math behind my suggested solution is fairly easy.

Comment: Mostly for mileage on the images used. If I use lines a pixel thick on say 1028x720 image the best I can get is maybe 15-30 minutes before the player is rewarded. This is less of an issue if I queue up some 10-5 images.